# How to implement nested query in sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

So i have this 2-layer query in node.js, each query could return multiple results. My code actually just ignores that for now. This is the best i can get, it seems working.

1. How to correct it please, i don't know how to callback for the 2nd one.
2. Also the db.close() is always called before the 2nd query finishes, even i have serialize().

   var getInfo1Db = function(callback) {
       var db = new sqlite3.Database("DB.sqlite3");

   ```
   var cnt = 0; 
   var info1JsonObj = [];

   db.all("select * from Info1DB", 
       function(err, rows) {

           db.serialize(function() {
               for(var ii=0, len=rows.length; ii<len; ii++) {

                   var t2 = rows[ii].info1;
                   var doorId =  ...

                   db.all("select * from DoorDB where ObjectID=" + doorId,
                       function(err, row2) {

                           if(err) {
                           } else {
                               var doorName = row2[0]...

                               var info1JsonElem = {
                                   "DoorName" : doorName
                               };

                               info1JsonObj.push(info1JsonElem);
                               cnt++;
                               if(cnt === rows.length) {
                                   callback(null, info1JsonObj);
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    ); // for the only door info based on door id

               } // for each row of info1

               db.close(); // why this finishes before the 2nd db.all
           } );  // end of serialize

   });
   ```

   };

Comment: why don't you write a single query instead of two (more like another query per each tuple in the first query)?

Comment: @dmg  i simplified the real problem, each query could return multiple results, then your 2nd query uses previous result, then your 3rd query uses ...  In the end i just do all these in perl, let node.js calls perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can't implement nested query in sqlite3's normal way. ( I mean you even can't do it in the `callback hell` way, because the `sqlite3` need to close the connection before another query called. otherwise you will always got error)

You have to use `Promise`, `async` and `await` to do this.
( it's worth to spend 30 minutes to learn these 3 words )

Step1. define a async function like this:

```
async query_1() {
  new Promise(resolve => {

      db = ...
      db.serialize( () => {
        db.get('select .. from ... where id = 1', [], (error, row) => {
           // here is the KEY: put the result into resolve 
           // this equals to the "return" statement in non-sync method.
           resolve(row)
        }
      })
      db.close()
  })
}
```

and also implement your query_2 function like this:

```
async query_2() {
  let query_1_result = await this.query_1()

  db = ...
  db.serialize( () => {
    db.get('select .. from ... where dependency_id = ' + query_1_result, [], (error, row) => {
       // other code here...
    }
  })
  db.close()
}
```

refer to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67881159/445908

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 function to do these ?

```
function db_query1(your_param,...., callback){
　　// database operation
   db.run( sql , [param,...] , function(err,rows){
      if(err) // return
      else{
         // get rows with callback
         callback(null, rows);
      }
   });
}

function db_query2(your_param,...., callback){
　　// database operation
   db.run( sql , [param,...] , function(err,rows){
      if(err) // return
      else{
         // get rows with callback
         callback(null, rows);
      }
   });
}
```

And call these function:

```
db_query1(....,function(err,result1){
   if(err) ...// return 
   // do the things with result1
   // And then call query2
   db_query2(....,function(err,result2){
      if(err) ...// return 
      // do the things with result1
   });
});
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promises.all`, an array and the second callback for node sqlite3 `db.each()` that is executed when all rows have been fetched. [Node Sqlite3 db.each usage](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) to simplify the nested query and

I cannot really get the meaning of the variables you are using thus I assume that each row in `Info1DB` has a one-to-many relationship with `DoorDB` on the field `doorId`.

```
async function getInfo (callback) {
    sql = "select * from Info1DB;";
    numVersions = 0;
    countVersions = 0;
    info1JsonObj = [];
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.each(sql, [], (err, info1Row) => {
            sql = "select * from DoorDB where ObjectID=?;";
                info1Row.doors = [];
            doorId = ...
            db.each(sql, [doorId], (err, doorRow) => {
                info1Row.doors.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(doorRow);
                    }
                }));
            }, (err, num) => {
                Promise.all(info1Row.doors)
                    .then((doors) => {
                        info1Row.doors = doors;
                        info1JsonObj.push(info1Row);
                        countVersions++;
                        if (countVersions == numVersions) {
                            callback(null, info1JsonObj);
                        }
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        callback(err, null);
                    });
            });
        }, (err, versions) => {
            numVersions = versions;
        });
    });
}
```